# minify javascript embedded into dll

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bundle, minify

I have a web application and i want minify a resource javascript embedded into a dll.
I know that using bundle i can minify resource with path, but in this case ther's no path to add because de javascript is added at run-time.

in the server control, in prerender function ther's this line code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(Me.GetType(), "ViewPage.js")
```

in assembly info

```
<Assembly: WebResource("ViewPage.js", "text/javascript")>
```

it's working but javascript is as well as.
Can i minify at run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the AArnott's JavascriptCssPackerTargets project:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/10/08/minify-your-embeddedresource-js-and-css-files-in-your-msbuild-project.aspx

Update:

This can help too:
http://blog.turlov.com/2009/11/automatically-compress-embedded.html